# Create event button that can read field of items that contain value in specific column

Tags: 2013

I built a SharePoint list with many column:

[image: List]

How to create an event button that can read items filtered and add values in a loop sms.addSMSRecipient(0033612 <--- here?); ?

At this moment I can read just one value

```
 if (Page.Request.QueryString["Telefono"] != null)
            {
                TextBox_numcell.Text = Page.Request.QueryString["Telefono"];

            }

  protected void Button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SMSCConnection smsc_connection = null;

            smsc_connection = new SMSCHTTPConnection();


            try
            {

                SMS sms = new SMS();
                sms.TypeOfSMS = SMSType.GOLD_PLUS;
                sms.addSMSRecipient(TextBox_numcell.Text);
                sms.addSMSRecipient("");
                sms.Message = TextBox_Messaggio.Text;
                sms.SMSSender = TextBox_Mittente.Text;
                sms.setImmediate(); 
                SendResult result = smsc_connection.sendSMS(sms);

            }
```

I would kindly get all fields "Telefono" of group1 filtered example:
and  add values in a loop sms.addSMSRecipient(0033612 <--- here?)
[image: List filtered]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for above mention scenario you can create a visual webpart with a button on it and on button click you call your respective task for example
    protected void Button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string strUrl = "Insert your site URL here";
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(strUrl))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            // choose the list
            SPList list = web.Lists["insert your list Name"];

```
        SPQuery myquery = new SPQuery();
        myquery.RowLimit = 100;
        myquery.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Telefono' /></OrderBy>";

        SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(myquery);

        foreach (SPListItem item in items)
        {
            // check the item for null
            if (item != null)
            {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

You can also refer [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1020663/Simple-Steps-to-Create-a-Visual-Web-Part-in-ShareP) for reference to create a visual webpart